# access httpcontext.session in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, saml-2.0, httpcontext

I need to get `HttpContext.Session` in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method. However I get `null` when I try to access `Httpcontext.Session`.

Below is my code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),

        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(
         PublicClientId,
         DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>(),
         HttpContext.Current),

       //AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),

        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),

        // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,

        RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider(
          DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

I use SAML where I set my `HttpContext` session value, but I need to re-check that `Session` value again into my `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`  method, but however the session is always null in here.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I need to re-check that Session value again [in] my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method.

Checking the session value in the `GrantResourceOwnerCredential` method is not a good idea. The session is stored in the cookie that comes with the request. Since the request comes in through the token endpoint, the request is not protected against tampering with the cookie. That means that a malicious user could tamper with the cookie and change the session.