# How can I make a session variable available to all controllers without accessing HttpContext in each controller?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I'm trying to make the `int` variable `BranchId` available through out my application via the use of `HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("BranchId").Value`.

As I gather from my own attempt, and from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661420/access-httpcontext-session-in-grantresourceownercredentials), this approach will not work:

Base controller class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Vaktliste.Controllers
{
    public class MyBaseControllerClass : Controller
    {
        public readonly int branchId;

        public MyBaseControllerClass()
        {
            var s = HttpContext.Session; // <-- This causes a NULL exception
            // SET THE VARIABLE HERE:
            BranchId = s.GetInt32("BranchId") != null
                ? s.GetInt32("BranchId").Value
                : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of another controller in the application:

```
namespace Vaktliste.Controllers
{
    public class BranchesController : MyBaseControllerClass
    {
        private readonly VaktlisteContext db;

        public BranchesController(VaktlisteContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            // USE THE VARIABLE HERE:
            if (id == null) id = BranchId;

            if (id == null) return NotFound();

            var branch = await db.Branches
                .Where(m => m.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (branch == null) return NotFound();

            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("BranchId", branch.Id);

            return View(branch);
        }
    }
}
```

I could of course do the `GetInt32("BranchId")` in every controller, but I want to keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). How can it be done?

Comment: You could make the branch id a Lazy<int> in the base class and then it would be available during the request (not the constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can achieve this with a property.  When the basecontroller is created, the httpcontext.session is null. If you use a property and only access it in your routes, the session should be available.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Vaktliste.Controllers
{
    public class MyBaseControllerClass : Controller
    {
        public readonly int branchId;
        protected int BranchId { 
            get { HttpContext.Session?.GetInt32("BranchId")?.Value ?? 0; }
            set { HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("BranchId", value); }
        }

        public MyBaseControllerClass()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then just access the property to get the value

```
namespace Vaktliste.Controllers
{
    public class BranchesController : MyBaseControllerClass
    {
        private readonly VaktlisteContext db;

        public BranchesController(VaktlisteContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            // USE THE VARIABLE HERE:
            id = id ?? BranchId;

            if (id == null) return NotFound();

            var branch = await db.Branches
                .Where(m => m.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (branch == null) return NotFound();

            BranchId = branch.Id;

            return View(branch);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `protected` variable and just use it to wrap your accessor:

```
protected int? BranchId
{
   get { return (HttpContext.Session["BranchId] as int?); }
   set { HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("BranchId", value);
}
```

Then update your second to last line as:

`this.BranchId = branch.Id;`

And of course, all subclassed controllers just access the protected variable.